# Sampling uniform equilibrium distribution with Markov Chain Monte Carlo

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, monte-carlo

I'm wanting to sample the discrete uniform distribution over $n = 10$ integers using MCMC. My question concerns the transition probability matrix, $P$. As I understand it, any symmetric, irreducible and aperiodic Markov Chain would converge to the uniform equilibrium distribution.

So I was wondering if there's any advantage in using some arbitrary symmetric matrix over the one that jumps to mind as the obvious choice which would be a $10\times10$ matrix with $1/10$ as every entry.

Comment: If you can sample from $U[1,10]$ (each row of the proposed matrix) directly, there is no need to run MCMC - you are just i.i.d. sample. The whole idea and use of MCMC is when you cannon sample from the whole space and only make local moves. So you can consider a lazy random walk where you just move R=L/stay with approximately equal probabilities (and wrap your interval into a circle). Mixing time ain't going to be good for this MCMC though.

Comment: Ah right so the matrix would be tridiagonal?

Comment: If you don't wrap it in a circle - yes. If you wrap it in the circle, you'll get two entries in the opposite corners as well.

Comment: Ah okay yeah, I was just thinking about this and came up with those two entries in the corners, it makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit of an overkill, but if you do want to do it, you probably still want to minimize the autocorrelation, so you should have zeros on the diagonal and $1/9$ off the diagonal.

Comment: Your suggestion introduces (negative) correlation, while OP's suggestion is uncorrelated.

Comment: Yeah, it's part of a MCMC course I'm taking so it's getting to grips with the basics of it with a simple example, thanks for the help though. Out of interest, is there any benefit in having 1/9 for all the off diagonals or just having, say two elements either side of the diagonal on each row?

Comment: @A.S.: You're right -- as I wrote, it minimizes autocorrelation :-) It depends on what this is being used for. Monte Carlo simulations often want to sample the sample space as efficiently as possible, so sampling the same point twice is a waste -- but there may well be applications where complete lack of correlation is preferable.

Comment: @bigbadpiano: That will make the results more correlated -- it would then take longer to get from one state to other states that are not directly accessible through a single transition. But this is all a bit speculative; to say something useful, we'd have to know what you want to use this for.

Comment: It's for a question in an introductory monte carlo simulations course. The question just asks which transition probability matrix you'd use to sample the discrete uniform distribution, then to prove the chain is irreducible, aperiodic and has the correct equilibrium distribution

Comment: @bigbadpiano: At that level of generality, without any particular application in mind, there's no clear advantage to any of the alternatives.

Comment: Ah okay then, thanks a lot, I was a bit confused by the generality and thought there must be some ideal way but I think I'll just go with the random walk method suggested by @A.S as this is closest to what we've done in class so far